# Extern variable with different types in C

Tags: c, casting, declaration, extern, linkage

I was testing out scopes and visibility when I came across this situation I can't find an explanation for :

I have two .c files :

**F1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Modify();

int i;
int j;

int main()
{
  i=1;

  printf("i (main 1) = %d\n", i);

  Modify();

  printf("i (main 2) = %d\n", i);

  return 0;
}
```

and **F2.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char i [10];
extern int j;

void Modify()
{
  j=0;
  i[0]='a';
  i[1]= 'b';
  i[4]= 'e';

  printf("i (Modify) = %c\n", i[0]);
  printf("j (Modify) = %d\n", j);
}
```

When I compile and link them to create the executable that I Launch, here is the result :

*i (main 1) = 1*

*i (Modify) = a*

*j (Modify) = 0*

*i (main 2) = 25185*

What is happening? Does i changes types? Does giving an array with a size overpowers the declaration of i in F1.c?

Thanks!

Comment: This is UB. A good linker will warn about this.

Comment: @o11c What does UB mean?

Comment: @CSstudZ You've broken the rules of the game and if your compiler and linker do produce a program, it isn't guaranteed to be a meaningful one. All bets are off. http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html

Comment: @PSkocik, oh so I have no hope of finding a logic behind the output??
Lol, I just tried removing the line *i[1] = 'b';* and now I get *i (main2) = 97*. I have no idea what is going on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is against the rules of C. External globals need to have consistent declarations. (That's why we use headers to maintain the consistency.) You've given your toolset permission to make a mess of things.

That being said, what's happening in your case is that the objects are simply overlaid (probably sufficient storage is being allocated for both `int`, and `char[10]`, sort of like if there was a `union` there. If only 4 bytes are allocated (just for the `int`, not the array) then the `i[4]` access will overwrite something or less likely cause a segfault.).

`25185` is `0x6261`, which assuming a little endian architecture corresponds to `{0x61, 0x62, 0x00, 0x00}`, i.e;, `{'a', 'b', 0, 0 }`. The `'e'` isn't included in that number because your architecture's `int`s are 4 bytes large and the `'e'` was put at the 5th byte.

Again, you're in the realm of UB, so none of this is guaranteed behavior.