# Extern declaration and definition type difference

Tags: c, type-conversion, extern

There was a question in our class about what will happen if we declare a variable as **extern long** in a .c file and then define that variable as **double** in another.c file.

When we tried to print the long variable we obviously got a garbage value or overflow value, I am not sure (i.e. It was some negative value — the same in everyone's device so probably not just a garbage value).

I want to understand what's going on inside the compiler and linker when we do this. And how the memory for the variable ends up having a garbage value or overflow value.
We also wanted to get the integer part of the variable defined as a double. Is there any way to do that without matching the **extern declaration** and **definition** type of the variable.
The *a.c file*

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern long x;

int main(){
    printf("%ld", x);
    return 0;
}
```

The *b.c file*

```
double x = 3.1456;
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: The linker for C doesn't generally care about types. It just links variables by name. But the compiler generates code in `a.c` that interprets the memory at that address as a `long`. It has no way of knowing that it actually contains a `double`.

Comment: Shouldn't the external reference be in `studio.h`? That would allow the compiler to notice the error.

Comment: When this came up in class, what did your teacher say?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extern variable with different types in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59913960/extern-variable-with-different-types-in-c)

Comment: *"It was Some negative value same in everyone's device so probably not just a garbage value ... how the memory for the variable ends up having a garbage value or overflow value"*. It's not a garbage value but a defined bit pattern where the contents of the memory were being used in a different way, as the compiler was instructed to use it. It can be a similar case when passing the wrong type for a `printf` format specifier - the function just believes what it was told. This say `0x12345678` is a different value in different contexts. Everything is a number - context is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As everybody says, this is undefined behaviour - the compiler is allowed to do anything. In reality, what is happening (probably, assuming a mainstream toolchain) is that, when the compiler compiles `b.c` it reserves probably eight bytes for the `double` representation of 3.1456, which, assuming IEEE double precision and a little endian platform is.

```
7c 61 32 55 30 2a 09 40
```

(bytes above are in hex)

When the compiler comes to compile `a.c` it assumes `x` is `long` and will treat it as such but will not allocate any space for it. It uses a placeholder address instead. The linker will then replace any occurrences of the placeholder with the real address from `b.c`

If the compiler has an eight byte `long`, it will interpret that as 0x40092a305532617c. If it has a four byte long, it will interpret it as 0x5532617c.

Note that there are lots of caveats to the above depending on compiler implementation and the architecture. This is why it's undefined behaviour. It's easier to let implementers handle it how they want than to enforce some particular behaviour, even emitting an error diagnostic.

> We also wanted to get the integer part of the variable defined as a double. Is there any way to do that without matching the extern declaration and definition type of the variable.

Simply casting a `double` to an `int` will get the integer part assuming all the bits fit in an `int` (if `int` is 32 bits and `double` is an IEEE double precision, the mantissa is 52 bits, which won't always fit).

```
// in b.c
 printf("%d\n", (int) x); // Prints 3
```

Comment: The IEEE-754 “double precision” (binary64) significand is 53 bits. 52 are encoded in the primary significand field, and one is encoded via the exponent field. Binary64 operations behave mathematically as if the significand is 53 bits, because it is. Also, “significand” is the preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point representation. “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. Significands are linear (adding to a significand adds to the value represented), mantissas are logarithmic (adding to a mantissa multiplies the value represented).

Answer (score 2):

The C 2017 standard 6.2.7-2 says:

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the
> behavior is undefined.

Comment: It is often a problem that the informative sections do not contain a complete reference to the normative clauses. I think the one covering this case is 6.2.7-2: "*All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.*". By the way, all of this is the same in C23 except that the informative section is J.5.12.

Comment: @nielsen I appreciate the reference and added it to the above.

Comment: That's correct, please never use Annex J as a source, since it isn't normative and as it happens also full with errors that will apparently never get corrected.

Comment: @Lundin Revised.

Answer (score 1):

> what's going on inside the compiler

Compiler generates code.

Each file is compiled separately.

One compiler [reads variable](https://godbolt.org/z/eWrxo55ds) `x` as `long` and puts it on stack and calls `printf`.

The other compiler defines variable `x` [with the value](https://godbolt.org/z/Y4xKbn6Go):

```
x:
        .long   1429365116
        .long   1074342448
```

The memory initialized as such for `x` is read as `long` variable in the other source code. In effect the string `4614265680293945724` (equal to `1074342448<<32|1429365116`) "happens" to be printed (on x86_64 on Linux in gcc compiler). Note `.long` in assembly != `long` in C language.

> linker when we do this

Linker just links, linker sees no types. Linker sees reference to an object named `x`, there is an object named `x` in `b.c`, great, let's link them.

> how the memory for the variable ends up having a garbage value or overflow value

`double` values *on x86_64 on gcc in linux* are represented as [IEEE 754 double-precision binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) format. The value `3.1456` is represented in IEEE 754 as (using [this](https://baseconvert.com/ieee-754-floating-point)) 0x40092A305532617C. Converting from hex, that is 4614265680293945724 in decimal.

> get the integer part of the variable defined as a double

To get the integer representation of the bytes that are composed inside a `double` variable, the common way *in C* is to use a union:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
   union double_to_int_u {
      long long ll;
      double d;
   };
   union double_to_int_u u;
   u.ll = 0;
   u.d = 3.1456;
   printf("%lld\n", u.ll);
}
```

Another way is to alias with `char` and collect the bytes. The endianess comes into play here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    double d = 3.1456;
    long long ll = 0;
    unsigned char *c = (char*)&d;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(d); ++i) {
        ll <<= 8;
        ll |= c[i];
    }       
    printf("%lld\n", ll);
}
```

If you want to however extract the "parts" from IEEE 754 number, the standard way would be to use  `frexp()` and `signbit()` functions from `math.h`. The "speed" and unsafe way would be to use implementation-defined behavior with bitfields like [in glibc](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/4290aed05135ae4c0272006442d147f2155e70d7/sysdeps/ia64/ieee754.h#L69).